# 1d Array - determine best container size with minimum waste

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, containers

EDIT: Thanks Alain for a proper description for this:

The problem is this: a shop that tries to find the optimal size of their cardboard boxes, to be able to pack all goods, and trying to minimize wasted space in the boxes.

Currently I have a dataset with volumes. I need to figure out if for example the amount of containers I can use is 5, what are the 5 best sizes to fit all those volumes? For example, this array contains my volume:

```
var numbers =[10, 20, 20, 30, 50, 50, 50, 80];
```

And to make it simple, I have 2 containers. Each with the size of 50 and 80.

10 fits in 50, but the waste is 40. 20 fits also in 50, but the waste is 30 and so on. 50 fits in 50, but the waste is 0. Same holds for 80. In total the waste is 120.

But what if the sizes were different? 60 and 80. Then the total waste would be 180.

```
(60-10) + (60-20) + (60-20) + (60-30) + (60-50) + (60-50) + (60-50) + (80-80)
```

My question is, what is the most efficient way to determine how big the sizes should be for the containers? Given that you know the amount of how many containers you can use and the numbers(in this case it was volume) in an array.

So for example, what if I didn't knew the sizes of my container should be 50 and 80. How would I have calculated the best correct size if I only know how many containers I can use and what volume each object has?

Is there some kind of algorithm for this, and if so, can you give an example? I tried looking things up like the bin packing, knapsack and k-means but they are not very clear to me how I can apply them to this problem. I just want to calculate which sizes are best suited to store all the volumes with minimal waste.

I hope I was clear with this example, if not please ask more about. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Sort your values, and go for decreasing order and if fits put it in. After the end of the loop, you should have the minimal waste...

Comment: So you can't put multiple objects in a container?

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto , but what if the size is unknown? I think with this approach you need to know the container sizes right?

Comment: @spug yes it's possible, I don't know if I have explained it correctly but in the sample I gave, I had 7 objects that could fit in a container size of 50, but I have to see for each object if it fits in the container or not.

Comment: @sabuzyra but in that case the waste can be reduced to zero in the first example, not 120 ...?

Comment: So is it correct to say you have two *types* of containers? Is the problem like a shop that tries to find the optimal size of their cardboard boxes to be able to pack all goods, trying to minimize wasted space in the boxes?

Comment: @spug yes but there is space left. The container size is 50 and my object has a size of 10. So there is like 40 space left. I need to do the iteration for every object I mean sorry. So even though I could for example put 5x10 in a 50 size containers, I should iterate it as a stand alone object. So putting an object with size 10 in a container of 50 is 40 waste.

Comment: What is *best correct* ? Your first question about minimum waste may be answerable, but your second one about the *best* size isnt.

Comment: @alain, I used 2 in this example, it could be 3, it could be 4, the thing is, based on the amount of containers I can use, and knowing the volume of each object, how many times can a single object fit in it without much waste. Maybe I should be a bit clear but it could also be boxes. I think I just change containers to boxes for better clarity.

Comment: @sabuzyra ah I see, so the answer to my original question was yes. Could have been more straightforward if you just told me.

Comment: @alain yes it certainly is the same problem.

Comment: @Jonasw , the best size would be when there is as least waste as possible. I need to calculate the size of the boxes which would prevent less waste.

Comment: @sabuzyra simply put the items randomly in the containers, sum up their size and youve got your containers size? Or am i getting sth completely wrog?

Comment: @Jonasw I updated my question, basically it's to see what the optimal cardboard box size is with minimal waste.

Comment: @sabuzyra so you have a certain amount of container sizes given? And the number of  container is free choosable?

Comment: @Jonasw no, the container size is chooseable. The number of containers that can be used isn't. For production I have 5 containers, but for simplicity I want to do it with 2 first before I move on. Unless I should start with 5. But yes it's 5 different containers, but the sizes of those 5 containers are not known. The sizes of those 5 containers should be determined by the volume in the array.

Comment: @sabuzyra then as i said, put the elems randomly in the containers then sum up their volume. Loss=0 ...

Comment: One of the containers has to be the same size as the largest element to get an optimal solution. The rest of the containers have to have the same sizes as other elements too, or the solution isn't optimal again. So with N different elements and M containers (M < N) the naive approach takes O(N choose M).

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be convert the array into a set to remove duplicate(s), then convert back to an array in order to sort it. Then reverse the order so that we have the biggest size of the goodies in front. Now, pre-processing step is done.

Next step is to declare the container availability, you can see the code and modify as you wish, in my example, I'll use 3 containers (or cardboard boxes). I modified the array to test some cases.

Iterate through the reversed array that you've made, if the container size is not equal to the current goodies size AND if you still have available container size, then reduce 1 container size availability and push the size to the container list. I put try and catch just to break out of iteration once you have no container size left to check. Lastly, fill up the rest of the goodies array with the smallest container that we've got.

This algorithm will be O(number of container_avail + number of remaining_goodies) [Basically, O(n)].

```
var numbers = [60, 40, 20, 20, 10, 50, 50, 50, 80];
var original_numbers_length = numbers.length;
console.log('Given unsorted goodies: ', numbers);
numbers = new Set(numbers);
numbers = Array.from(numbers)
numbers.sort();
numbers.reverse();

var container_avai = 3;
var container_size = 0;
var container_list = [];

console.log('All goodies: ', numbers);
console.log('Given container available: ', container_avai);

var BreakException = {}

try{
    numbers.forEach(function(item){
    if( container_size != item && container_avai > 0){
        container_avai -= 1;
        container_size = item;
        container_list.push(container_size);
    }
    if ( container_avai == 0){
        throw BreakException;
    }
});}
catch (e) {
    // Done
}
remaining_goodies = original_numbers_length - container_list.length;
smallest_container = container_list[container_list.length - 1];

for (i = 0; i < remaining_goodies; i++){
    container_list.push(smallest_container);
}

console.log('Appropriate containers are: ', container_list);
```

The output I got:

```
Given unsorted goodies:  [ 60, 40, 20, 20, 10, 50, 50, 50, 80 ]
All goodies:  [ 80, 60, 50, 40, 20, 10 ]
Given container available:  3
Appropriate containers are:  [ 80, 60, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50 ]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved optimally in O(kn^2) time and O(kn) space for n items and k container sizes using [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming):

```
perl -le '$b = shift; @x = @ARGV; sub f { my ($n, $k) = @_; return 0 if $n == 0; return 1e9 if $k == 0; if (!defined $m[$n][$k]) { my ($t, @best) = (0, 1e9, 0); for (my $i = $n - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) { $t += $x[$n - 1] - $x[$i]; my $y = $t + f($i, $k - 1); if ($y < $best[0]) { @best = ($y, $i); } } $m[$n][$k] = [@best]; } return $m[$n][$k][0]; } print "Cost: ", f(@x + 0, $b); my $i = @x; for (my $j = $b; $j > 0; --$j) { print $x[$i - 1]; $i = $m[$i][$j][1]; }' 2 10 20 20 30 50 50 50 80
Cost: 120
80
50
```

Space usage can be further reduced to O(n) with a different evaluation order.  The first argument is the number of containers, and the rest are the item sizes in nondecreasing order.  I found the question and author's comments extremely confusing, despite attempts at clarification from other users, so I don't feel too bad about letting him/her translate this from Perl to Javascript.